# PCRE to find all urls without file extensions that include #, ?, & etc

Tags: regex, pcre

Very much a rookie question - have the following which I am using to look for any urls without the following extensions (seems to work):

`href="\S*(?i)(?<!\.html)(?<!\.pdf)(?<!\.doc)(?<!\.docx)(?<!\.ppt)(?<!\.pptx)(?<!\.xls)(?<!\.xlsx)(?<!\.jpg)(?<!\.jpeg)(?<!\.eps)"`

Where I am struggling is trying to figure out how to also find file names with extensions and exclude such as:
`test.html#help`
`test.html?help`
`test.html?help&please`

Not sure how to take something like this `(?<!\.html)` and add a wildcard to handle anything after .html

Did some more testing via an online regex tester site and this seems to work - matches any of the file extensions including test.html#help etc :
`href="\S*(?i)(((?<=\.html)\S*)|((?<=\.pdf)\S*)|((?<=\.doc)\S*)|((?<=\.ppt)\S*)|((?<=\.xls)\S*)|((?<=\.jpg)\S*)|((?<=\.jpeg)\S*)|((?<=\.eps)\S*))"`

but this does not work at all:
`href="\S*(?i)((?<!\.html)\S*)"`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
href="(?<url>.+?\.(?!(html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps)).*?)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/SPjvkR/1

- `href="` matches the characters `href="` literally (case sensitive)
- Named Capture Group url `(?<url>.+?\.(?!(html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps)).*?)`
  (`?<url>` is what gives the capturing group the name.  It can be omitted if you don't want the capturing group to have a name or can be replaced with `?:` to make the it a non-capturing group.  Naming can just make it more convenient to get the group's value in later code if needed, but in your case I don't think it matters
- `.+?` matches any character (except for line terminators) between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `\.` matches the character `.` with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)
- Negative Lookahead `(?!(html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps))`
  Assert that the Regex below does not match

  - 2nd Capturing Group `(html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps)`
- `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators) between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `"` matches the character `"` with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive)

---

**Update**

New regex based on comments

```
href="((?!.*\.(?:html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps)).*?)"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKQsvC/1)

- `href="` matches the characters href=" literally (case sensitive)
- 1st Capturing Group `((?!.*\.(?:html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps)).*?)`

  - Negative Lookahead `(?!.*\.(?:html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps))`
    Assert that the Regex below does not match

    - `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
    - `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    - `\.` matches the character . with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)
    - Non-capturing group `(?:html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps)`
  - `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*?` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `"` matches the character " with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Daniel - thank you. It definitely works. Now I just need to do some reading to understand how/why it actually works (that way I don't keep asking the same questions over and over).

Comment: Something I should have added to my original request (I had made it simple so I would understand any possible answer).......your solution works great - thank you. The last part of the regex makes sense - \.(?!(html|xlsm|pdf|doc|ppt|jpg|jpeg|eps)).*? - not sure about the first part though - ?<url>.+?. I need to be able to also handle if the URL has additional periods in the URL - example: test.test.html#help OR https://www.test.com/test.html

Comment: I've updated my answer with some additional explanation.  Does that help?

Comment: Daniel - it definitely helps. My background is more sql, vbscript, html, css etc. Lots to learn on my end - even for just the simple stuff. And thank you.

Comment: @gully53, I updated my answer with a new (and hopefully improved) regex for you.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Awesome - thank you. Works great. For some reason I thought I would need to check the end of the string - somehow use some sort of combination of ?!.html, *?, and $. Guess why this is the reason I don't do this for a living.  Daniel - thanks again.

Comment: Just ran the regex against my webpages and only found one "false-positive" - html such as this: href="test.html" alt="test"><img src="test.jpg"> It seems that the 2nd extension in the html (jpg) somehow stops the regex from working?

Comment: Did a search on this forum....seems just about everyone is interested in being able to match with double quotation marks within the outer ones....for me, just the opposite, since my text string is a url that I am matching.....it would be just "whatever" and never "whatever "whatever" whatever".

Comment: Okay, if this doesn't work I think I'm going to have to tap out...  https://regex101.com/r/g3TNa9/1

Comment: Jackpot.....you got it (works for all scenarios on end). Thank you very much.

Comment: hi, @Daniel I want a regex like that with a little difference also, **get all URLs that aren't file**. get example.com/asdas/asdas but don't get example.com/abc.jpg can you help me? [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/RRIAmt/1)